# How to specify logging.config when multiple Spring Boot Apps are deployed on tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, logging, log4j2

I have multiple spring boot apps (X,Y,Z) packaged as war files deployed on my tomcat. I want to use log4j2 as my logging system for my applications. So, to change the logging system of say X, in tomcat I am setting Sping Boot Propery 'logging.config' value to point to /tomcat/apps/X/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2-spring.properties. By doing this logging works fine for X.

**Flashback:**
If we specify **logging.config=classpath:log4j2.properties**  in application.properties, then logging works when we do Run as Java Application in Eclipse. But, Logging does not work when we deploy it as a WAR file on tomcat.
To get it working, I had to put logging.config= {Path-to-myapp}/log4j2.properties in tomcat/bin/setenv.bat.

My question is if I have multiple applications, then how do I set logging.config for each Spring Boot App.

> Since logging is initialized before the ApplicationContext is created,
>   it is not possible to control logging from @PropertySources in Spring
>   @Configuration files. The only way to change the logging system or
>   disable it entirely is via System properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is a bug. The behaviour of **log4j2.properties/log4j2-spring.properties** and **log4j2-spring.xml** is not same. If we use log4j2.properties, then **logging.config=classpath:log4j2.properties** should be specified. On the other hand, If we use **log4j2-spring.xml**, then there is no need to specify **logging.config**.

In my opinion, this is an important bug that needs to be fixed to allow multiple Spring Boot Apps to deploy on the same server.

Fix should be made to support **log4j2.properties** in **org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem.getCurrentlySupportedConfigLocations()**

Answer (score 2):

I have renamed application.properties and set the log4j config by making the following changes:

```
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyApplication.class)
    .properties("spring.config.name:new-app-properties-name")
    .build()
    .run(args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(MyApplication.class).properties("spring.config.name: new-app-properties-name");
}

/**
 * Set log4j2.xml location
 */
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    servletContext.setInitParameter("logging.config", "/my-app/config/log4j2.xml");
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
}
}
```

Comment: onStartup is not  called, in my case

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom logging path for each application, something like this:

```
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    org.apache.http: ERROR
  file: ${catalina.base:.}/logs/app-${app-number}.log
  pattern:
    file: ${logPattern}
    console: ${logPattern}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, in that case I made following changes:

- Externalize the log4j2.properties file from applications like as you did, mentioned the external location of file in .env file.(IN your case its in .bat file of tomcat). Each spring boot refer this file only.
- In that log4j2.properties file, we have created separate appender and logger for each  service and configure it.

This is not a exact solution but upto certain points it is working.

For each service, if you want to do it then it means you have to create each file and location and all ... and its not manageble after certain point.

As mentioned in earlier comment, need some mechanism to handle this kind of situation in mannered and structural way.